# Modify color and font-size by means of QStyledItemDelegate

Tags: python, pyqt5

I use QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate for some rows of a table created by reading a database.

```
class ItemDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._values = dict()

    def add_text(self, text, row):
        self._values[row] = text

    def initStyleOption(self, option, index):
        super().initStyleOption(option, index)
        row = index.row()
        if row in self._values:
            option.text = self._values[row]
            option.displayAlignment = QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter
```

```
       ...some code...
       self.delegate = ItemDelegate()
       table.setItemDelegate(self.delegate)

       self.delegate.add_text(self.first_text, 0)
       self.delegate.add_text(self.second_text, 1)
       self.delegate.add_text(self.third_text, 18)
```

The three texts are positioned correctly but I don't know how to get
for self.first_text: color, font-size and font-weight
for self.third_text: background
If I have to create a "delegate" for each option, how do I then insert it into table.setItemDelegate (self.delegate)?

Comment: [`setItemDelegateForRow()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#setItemDelegateForRow). Or just do the same as you did for `add_text` for the other properties.

Comment: @musicamente what I think could be fine was:

`'item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(self.value)
item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
item.setBackground(QtGui.QColor('#000099'))
item.setText(self.bottom_data)
self.delegate.add_text(item, 33)
but I get this:

option.text = self._values[row]
TypeError: QTableWidgetItem cannot be converted to a C/C++ QString in this context

Comment: `item` is a QTableWidgetItem, not a string. I don't understand what would be the point of overriding the text in the delegate using the text that the item already has.

Comment: The point is that I don't know how to override it.

Comment: The function is correct, you're giving the wrong argument: it should be a string, but you're providing a QTableWidgetItem. But, as said, it's not clear what would be the point of overriding the displayed text with the **same** text. Please try to clarify what you're trying to achieve with that (and why).

Comment: [link](https://i.imgur.com/Uu8Lov2.jpg) [link](https://i.imgur.com/Ilm8syY.jpg) I would like the text in first row of the 1st pucture = bold + color --- same pic,2nd line just bold --- 2nd pic last text with a different background

Comment: As long as you're not using stylesheets, you don't need any of that: just use the relative functions of QTableWidgetItem: [`setFont()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidgetitem.html#setFont), [`setForeground()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidgetitem.html#setForeground), [`setBackground()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidgetitem.html#setBackground). Again, as said, there's really no point in overriding the text with the same text of the item.

Comment: At the end you forced me to check carefully my code just to discover that was meaningless to call delegate since I can get what I want with rowspan. Thank you